# How to insert integer values with query in MySQL in R?

Tags: mysql, r

I come to the situation where I need to insert the integer values in the table with query which is written in R. for Example:

```
>n1<-20
>n2<-30
>library(DBI)
>library(RMySQL)
>drv<-dbDriver("MySQL")
>con<-dnConnect(drv,user="root",password="sam123",dbname="user")
>dbSendQuery(con,"insert into test values(n1,n2);") # Problem with this lines only
```

following error I am getting:

Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: Unknown column 'n1' in 'field list')

Please help me out of these problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the paste function to concatenate

```
 dbSendQuery(con,paste("insert into test values(",n1,",",n2,");",sep=""));
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working fine for me.If possible can you explain me that "how the above code is working?"

Comment: @user1985919 the paste function is the concatenation function for R. It takes as input strings (eg "insert into test values") and variables (eg n1, n2). the "," inside the function just indicates "concatenate", while sep parameter acts as "concatenate by". you can always type ?paste and see the examples provided. your original code used n1 and n2 within quotes, and hence it was not interpreted as variable names, but literally as the string "n1,n2"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$dbSendQuery( con, "insert into test values($n1, $n2)" )
```