# How to fix dbWriteTable error "unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbWriterTable' for signature...?"

Tags: mysql, r, database, dbconnection

I want to insert data in MySQL from a dataframe in R. I managed to connect without problems from R to MySQL using dbConnect, however when I try to insert my data using dbWriteTable I keep getting the error

`unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbWriterTable' for signature '"integer", "character", "data.frame"'`.

Now, I've tried the proposed solution mentioned here [How to resolve this error--dbWriteTable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210394/how-to-resolve-this-error-dbwritetable) but this solution doesn't work for me. My original code was

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "Date", france$Date)
```

because my table in MySQL is called `Date` and my dataframe in R is called `france` and has a column `Date`containing dates (the type of this column is date too). After the proposed solution, my code becomes

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "Date", data.frame(dat=france$Date), row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

but I'm getting the same error. I tried adding `field.types=list("date")` as mentioned in the following solution [RMySQL dbWriteTable with field.types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864174/rmysql-dbwritetable-with-field-types?rq=1) but I get the same error.

Finally, I've tried to use `dbSendQuery` together with `paste()` to insert manually my data as suggested here [How to insert integer values with query in MySQL in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681248/how-to-insert-integer-values-with-query-in-mysql-in-r) but I get the same error again!

This is driving me crazy. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this:`dbWriteTable(con, "table_name", r_df, field.types = NULL, row.names = FALSE, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE, allow.keywords = FALSE)`. Also you have variables named as Date which could potentially give u an error.

Comment: By "r_df" do you mean france$Date? My dataframe is called "france" and the column is called "Date". If so, then I'm still getting the same error with your suggested code.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with other examples. For example, I defined df <- data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4)) and I created a table in MySQL as follows: CREATE TABLE mytable (ID int); then I try dbWriteTable(conn,"mytable",df$a) but I get the same error. Also when I try dbWriteTable(conn, "mytable", df$a, field.types = NULL, row.names = FALSE, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE, allow.keywords = FALSE) is the same problem

Comment: try assigning france$date to an object and then insert that.

Comment: Nothing changed. I defined `df<-france$Date` and then tried `dbWriteTable(conn, "Date",df)` and `dbWriteTable(conn, "Date", df, field.types = NULL, row.names = FALSE, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE, allow.keywords = FALSE)`. I'm getting the same error in both cases.

Comment: Also try specifying MySQL::dbWriteTable so that there is no issue in the namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try connecting to your database? I was having the same error and when I checked connection, it was broken. Make sure you check the connection to db and run the dbWriteTable command next. It should work

Comment: I remember I restarted MySQL and the problem was gone. So I guess your answer works. Interesting to see a reply 4 years later lol

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error because the object I was providing to `dbWriteTable()` wasn't a data.frame.

To fix it, I simply convert the object to a data.frame first

```r
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
dbWriteTable(con, "mydbtable", dat)
```